# how to keep printing a string when holding a certain key

Tags: python, printing, keyboard

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        print('a')
        break
```

This is my code it prints a when I press b.
but I want it to keep printing a when I'm holding b how do I do this.

Comment: does `while keyboard.is_pressed('b')` not work?

Comment: I tried that and if i press b it keeps printing 'a' infinitely

Comment: Try removing ```break```.

Answer (score 1):

I use this module `pynput` mostly for mouse events, but it handles **keyboard** events too.

Here is the link:   https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

This library allows you to control and monitor input devices.
Currently, mouse and **keyboard input** and monitoring are supported.

Instruction for keyboard midway down the page:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
```

or more appropriately use `pynput.keyboard.Listener` like this:

```
from pynput import keyboard
```

The code below detects multiple inputs.  You would have to modify it for the `a` to `b` example given in the original question.

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a small delay after the print function to allow the program to re-evaluate if the input is still being pressed?

```
import keyboard
import time

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        print('a')
        time.sleep(0.1)
```